# When should method overloads be refactored?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented-design, method-overloading

When should code that looks like:

```
DoThing(string foo, string bar);

DoThing(string foo, string bar, int baz, bool qux);

...

DoThing(string foo, string bar, int baz, bool qux, string more, string andMore);
```

Be refactored into something that can be called like so:

```
var doThing = new DoThing(foo, bar);

doThing.more = value;
doThing.andMore = otherValue;

doThing.Go();
```

Or should it be refactored into something else entirely?

In the particular case that inspired this question, it's a public interface for an XSLT templating DLL where we've had to add various flags (of various types) that can't be embedded into the string XML input.

Comment: repetitive `string foo, string bar` are a violation of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself "Don't repeat yourself") principle. [Extract class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) refactoring typically makes sense in cases like you describe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the common approach is to encapsulate some (or all) of the parameters into a class and have that as a parameter:

```
DoThing(string foo, string bar, DoThingParameters parameters = null);
```

If you use C#, you can then write those parameters directly inline when calling the method:

```
DoThing(foo, bar, new DoThingParameters { More = value, AndMore = otherValue });
```

Answer (score 1):

Both work, though I personally dislike assigning public members or properties like that if these members or properties are used directly for one purpose.

In other words, if you have a logger class, you shouldn't have to assign "logger.message" and then call "log()", since message is used strictly for the log method, hence it should be passed.

Understandably, I can see the need for doing such things in order to avoid refactoring code.  Here are a couple things you could do instead:

1. Consider passing non-specific parameters in the constructor rather than the method itself.  What I mean by non-specific parameters are parameters which aren't specific to a particular method but control behavior that isn't likely to change in the instance.  Returning to the logger class example, such a parameter might be the directory where the log file is saved.
2. Consider passing a key-value map containing all parameters.  This is the preferred method for passing non-descript parameters to third party libraries anyway.  If you find yourself dealing with large amounts of parameters to handle, then this might be preferable.    A good example of this might be instantiating a database connection using many of the database-specific parameters rather than having to have a static method for each database.  The method can then pull whatever parameters it finds that it can use.  However, I recommend that if you do it this way that you consider eliminating the other method signatures and forcing all calls to use this key-value system for consistency.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was tempted to say that in a language with reasonable literal maps I'd just use Dothing({'foo': 'bar' ...), or of course named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing here is the telescoping constructor anti-pattern.

IMHO you should refactor to public members only if it's a simple class used to store data. Otherwise, your class looks like a good candidate for the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). You can use it to:

- encapsulate default member-values logic - set those values from inside the builder instead of setting them for each object you construct using it's members public access
- gain the ability to respond to inappropriate initialization - when the object is constructed from the builder you determine inside the builder what to do when not all required values were set

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, though it's not actually a constructor (perhaps it should be, but that's another question). The telescoping constructor anti-pattern is definitely something I'll look into.